# What can be the reason to have only two installation option-"replace" and "something else"?

Tags: installation, 12.04

Here a picture, what can be the reason so I would be able to fix it?
[image]

It's in hebrew but the icons are as known.

Thank for helping!

Comment: Please can you run Gparted an post us a picture of what it shows??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you only get the `install alongside` if there is more than 1 OS.
- you only get the `use free space` if there is free space available on the harddisc.
- you get the upgrade option if there is an upgrade possible (and 12.04 had not got one).

Any more options you miss?